# MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount slows down execution time on my CPU

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have the following program (that I got from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx) that splits a task up using **Parallel.For** loop

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();


        Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
        {
            var result = SumRootN(i);
            Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
        });

        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static double SumRootN(int root)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I run this test several times I get times of:

1992, 2140, 1783, 1863 ms etc etc.

My first question is, **why are the times always different??** I am doing the exact same calculations each time yet the times vary each time.

Now when I add in the following code to make use of all the available processors on my CPU:

```
        var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount    (On my CPU this is 8)
        };

        Parallel.For(2, 20, parallelOptions, (i) =>
        {
            var result = SumRootN(i);
            Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
        });
```

I notice that the execution times actually increase!! The times are now:

2192, 3192, 2603, 2245 ms etc etc.

**Why does this cause the times to increase?  Am I using this wrong?**

Comment: What else is running on your system when you run the tests? Are you compiling in Release mode? Is a debugger attached? Is a profiler attached?

Comment: To get really comparable results, avoid outputs to the console from those threads.

Comment: I have Outlook open, EverNote open and Chrome webbrowser.

Comment: Its in Release mode and no debugger or anything is attached.

Comment: I think this is the Pigeonhole principle at work.  You ask 8 threads to do 18 jobs, the last 2 jobs take as much time as 8 jobs.  When you remove the limit, the TP scheduler allows *more* than 8 threads to start because they take too much time.  That will slow down each job but can get rid of the last 2.

Answer (score 22):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx

> By default, [`For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides.  Changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

This means that setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to the number of processors will in fact limit the capacity of the `Parallel.For` loop to use the optimal amount of threads for the work load. For example, I have a migration job that uses close to 60 threads on around 600 iterations of long-running code, a lot more than the *1 thread per processor* limit that you're trying to set.

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` or `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` should only be used if you explicitly need to prevent more than a given number of threads from executing. For example, if using an Access database, I would set it to 64, because that's the maximum number of concurrent connections that can be handled by Access for a single process.

Comment: Good answer. As mentioned, it is best to not set this explicitly unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: I actually changed the value of MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ENvironment.ProcessorCount to MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 and saw that it ran faster. You see I'm trying to create a test tool that is used to test how long different CPUs perform a task and I want to have the same test for each CPu thats why I want to set a limit on the number of Threads.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me the following.  If I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount (Which is 8) does that mean one thread is running on each processor so that means the task is truely being executed in parallel? And if I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to be 16 then that would mean that there are 2 threads running on each processor, but that each of these two threads have to switch between each other so it not true parallel processing??

Comment: With TPL, you cannot assume by default that a specific number of threads will be created and executed simultaneously. It will create/run as many threads as needed for the work load. You could try to run it with [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) as well as [ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) set to 8, but I'm not even sure that would guarantee 8 threads. Also, you would need to consider the thread handling overload.

Comment: I think it's important to differentiate between CPU-bound tasks and IO-bound tasks. Your long-running code is likely IO-bound, so it makes sense to use more than one thread per core. But the code in this question is CPU-bound, where it's usually best to use one thread per core.