# Throttling Message Queue Consumption While Using Parallellism

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was consuming messages from a message queue and processing them in parallel using `Task.Run()`. But I want to throttle the speed of consumption to a certain maximum number of threads **and not consume from the message queue until the thread count drops below that.**

Let's say I want max 100 threads. In that case, when a 100 threads is reached, it should stop consuming from the message queue. When a message processing task is completed and the number of threads drops to 99, it should consume one more message from the queue.

I tried to use `TransformBlock` for this purpose and here is a sample code for demonstration purposes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        object syncObj = new object();
        int i = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async Task<bool> ProcessMessage(string message)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            lock (syncObj)
            {
                i++;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);
            }
            return true;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var processor = new TransformBlock<string, bool>(
                    (str) => ProcessMessage(str),
                    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }
                    );

            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                await processor.SendAsync("a");
            }


    }
}
```

Throttling the number of parallel tasks works as expected but all messages are sent to the TransformBlock at once, so `SendAsync` loop ends before the tasks are processed.

I want it to continue accepting messages as long as the number of threads is below the max. allowed parallelism but wait when 100 is reached.

Is there a way to do this using TransformBlock or should I resort to some other method?

Comment: Why not use Parrallel.For instead of thr for loop and pass the MaxDegreeOfParallelism inside? Also tasks arenot thread, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806238/maxdegreeofparallelism-environment-processorcount-slows-down-execution-time-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow blocks have input buffers. This input buffer acts as a queue.

If you want to keep the messages in your *own* queue, you can do something close to what you want by restricting the number of items the dataflow block is willing to receive:

```
var processor = new TransformBlock<string, bool>(
    (str) => ProcessMessage(str),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
      BoundedCapacity = 100,
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100,
    }
);
```

Note that `BoundedCapacity` includes the items being processed by the block. Since `BoundedCapacity == MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, this essentially turns off the dataflow block's queue.

> so SendAsync loop ends before the tasks are processed.

It would still end when there are (up to) 100 tasks to be processed. If you want to wait until all items have *finished* processing, then call `Complete()` and `await` `Completed`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the BoundedCapacity. I will try it as soon as I can. Since I will be constatntly listening to the messages from the queue in a while loop, I don't think I will need to call Complete(). I will rely on BoundedCapacity and awating on SendAsync.

Comment: When I add BoundedCapacity=100, Debug.Writeline does not work after 100 iterations.

Comment: @hakanviv You need to get the results out of the `TransformBlock`. Link it to another block or add a consumer.

Comment: I am kind of confused. I am not really interested in the dummy result of the ProcessMessage method, I just want it to output to the debug output window. Do you mean it won't continue unless I link it to another block or add a consumer? Is it possible for you to show this on the original code I posted?

Comment: Correct. Until the item passes *out* of the block, it's still considered "in" the block and counts towards the `BoundedCapacity`. If you just want to drain the items, you can hook the transform block up to a buffer block: `var buffer = new BufferBlock<bool>(); processor.LinkTo(buffer);`. Or if you really don't need the output from the transform block, consider using an `ActionBlock` instead.